# Angularjs inheriting parent scope confusion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a controller that's inside another controller.

```
<div ng-controller="post">
  <div ui-if="isAllowed">
    <footer ng-controller="footer"></footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

I believe the ui-if creates a new scope so there's 3 scopes here.

I want the footer controller to be able to access the scope of post.

```
.controller('post', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = "bar"
})
```

I can easily do `$scope.$parent.$parent.foo` but I read that scopes are supposed to automatically inherit from the parent, and the parent thing is just super unwieldy.

Quote from Angularjs wiki:

> (If you really want to share data via controllers scope inheritance,
>   there is nothing you need to do. The child scope will have access to
>   all of the parent scope properties. See also Controller load order
>   differs when loading or navigating)

How do I access foo from the footer scope?

Comment: You just directly access them as if they were in your main scope.  [Plunk Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0a4mFJdSHs275tqCpYvk?p=preview)

Comment: @rGil oh you're right. I was looking at Batarang which showed the scopes separately, but now I realize that's not what that means haha. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As wiki said, you do not need to do anything. Just access it via its name.

```
<div ng-controller="post">
  <div ui-if="isAllowed">
    <footer ng-controller="footer">
        {{ fooB }} 
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>

function post($scope) {
    $scope.fooA = 'Foo A';
}

function footer($scope) {
    $scope.fooB = $scope.fooA + " and Foo B";
}
```

For instance above will render `Foo A and Foo B`

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/SNLNQ/31/)

Comment: What could the problem be if this in not working? I'm using Angular-loader and when I try to call methods on a parentscope, I get an 'undefined' error that method doesn't exist on object? Any ideas how to remedy that?

Comment: An 'isolated' scope in a directive is a reason why this will *not* work. NB: setting ```scope:true``` in the directive definition ensures you don't get an isolated scope but get a normal one which will inherit properties from the ancestor scope(s).