# AngularJS scope inheritance explanation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

I have an issue with scope inheritance in AngularJS. The issue is simlar to [Angularjs inheriting parent scope confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781391/angularjs-inheriting-parent-scope-confusion) but somehow the answer doesn't seem to apply to me.

I have a bunch of controllers (using some external components so I don't have full control over all controllers used) that are nested. The outermost controller and the innermost controller are defined by myself like so:

```
<div ng-controller="my-outer-controller">
  <div ng-controller="not-mycontroller">
    <div ng-controller="more-controllers">
      <div ng-controller="my-inner-controller">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

function myOuterController(@scope) {
    @scope.someFunction = function() {
    }
}


function myInnerController(@scope) {
    // This function does not exist here!
    @scope.someFunction();
}
```

The function someFunction() is not available in the inner controller. First I thought there must be some directive that makes an isolated scope in between but when I when I do something like the following it does work:

```
@scope.$parent.$parent.someFunction()
```

Just when I thought I had a pretty good understanding as to how Angular scopes work they knock me back down to earth.

I'm sure there's a good explanation as to why this is happening, but I can't see it. I thought that any property you can access via $parent is automatically inherited by the child scope.

Comment: Could the `not-my-controller` have been created by a directive? If so, it may be created differently, resulting in your issue.

Comment: Dunno, but your problem works here: http://jsfiddle.net/SNLNQ/61/

Comment: Have you checked out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/2874153?

Comment: Isolated scopes can access parents too.

Comment: @Erex I have, which is why I thought I understood how it worked which didn't seem to be the case :(.

Comment: @zeroflagL I thought isolated scopes were a new line of ancestry from the rootscope, meaning they have a parent, but just in a different tree than the other scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I thought this may help other users facing your issue.

I suggest trying using the alias syntax on your controller.

It will simplify your code and probably clarify what you're trying to do.

The alias syntax avoids injecting $scope directly and makes clearer which controller one is using.

[Check this awesome explanation out](http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/).

I hope it helps.